# ASP.net Calendar Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

i am trying to set the selected date of a calendar from SQL table. just displaying the date from the table onto the Calendar . My problem is in the last line.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        Calendar2.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
        SVCID = (string)(Session["SVCID"]);
        CustID = (string)(Session["CUSTID"]);
        int SVC_ID = System.Convert.ToInt32(SVCID);
        int Cust_ID = System.Convert.ToInt32(CustID);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lg_db"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Customers where Cust_ID = @CID", con))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", CustID);
                sqlDa.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    TB_Cname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Cust_Name"].ToString();
                    TB_Cphone.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Cust_phone"].ToString();
                    TB_Cmobile.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Cust_Mobile"].ToString();
                    TB_Cadd.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Cust_Add"].ToString();
                    DDL_PType.DataTextField = dt.Rows[0]["Cust_City"].ToString();
                    DDL_City.DataTextField = dt.Rows[0]["Cust_City"].ToString();
                    con.Close();
                }
                using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select * From SVC where SVC_ID = @SID", con))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", SVC_ID);
                    sqlDa2.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DDL_PType.DataTextField = dt.Rows[0]["Product_type_ID"].ToString();
                        DDL_Model.DataTextField = dt.Rows[0]["Product_ID"].ToString();
                        TB_serial.Text = dt.Rows[0]["SerialNumber"].ToString();
                        TB_Symptom.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Symptom"].ToString();
                        Calendar2.SelectedDate = dt.Rows[0]["Symptom"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

this code shows an error :

> "Cannot convert Type string to datetime"

Thank you

Comment: The error is clear. You need a DateTime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Calendar2.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Symptom"].ToString());
```

and i guess you are using the wrong field here, its a typo:

`dt.Rows[0]["Symptom"].ToString()`   i think is not the `Symptom` field you want to set a `SelectedDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar2.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();